# Using Azure SignalR invalid negotiation response received

Tags: azure, blazor, signalr

I am currently trying to use Azure SignalR in my Blazor app but I am currently experiencing difficulties which what looks like authentication errors.

I have set it up in my `Program.cs` file to include the Azure SignalR:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();
```

I have then added my connection string into the `appsettings.json` which is validated as when running the application I get the following message:

> Hub is now connected to '(Primary)xxx.service.signalr.net')

I have mapped my hub within my `Program.cs`

`app.MapHub<MessageHub>('/messagehub');`

However when I try to connect to the hub I get the following issue:

> Invalid negotiation response received.

I believe this to be me having authentication within my application and this error is being produced as a result of an unauthenticated error.

However, how can I authenticate with Azure and use that hub?

Comment: Can we check how you build your Hub? It's when you use the `HubConnectionBuilder`. Also check the CORS in Azure SignalR if your client is allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app) to use Azure **SignalR** services in Blazor App.

I hope you followed the same way. If not follow the below workaround
use latest **Microsoft.Azure.SignalR** package in your application
I have added the connection string of azure **SignalR** in a **`appsettings.json`** file

```json
  "Azure": {
    "SignalR": {
      "Enabled": true,
      "ConnectionString": "<SignalR Connection String>"
    }
  },
  # use ServerStickyMode to avoid Inconsistent UI state management. If you are using many servers
"Azure:SignalR:ServerStickyMode": "Required"
```

I am using endpoints to Map the Hub.

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/Fallback page");
    endpoints.MapHub<YourHub>('/YourHub');
});
```

Add the **Azure SignalR** service in a **ConfigureServices**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();
    ...
}
```

After configuring these you can be able to authenticate your hub.

If still facing issue add the below line of code in your **ConfigureServices** to know the detailed error.

```cs
     services.AddSignalR(
                s => 
                {
                    s.EnableDetailedErrors = true;                    
                });
```

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72820217/blazor-server-and-signalr-and-azure-ad) thread for similar kind of issue