# Use ASP.NET Core SignalR with Blazor: Error Invalid negotiation response received

Tags: signalr-hub, microsoft-identity-platform

I followed the instructions to the T from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio). But I keep getting an error message:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer: Warning: Unhandled exception rendering component: Invalid negotiation response received.

System.IO.InvalidDataException: Invalid negotiation response received.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '<' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issue with Microsoft.Identity and SignalR working together on a Blazor application. More information can be found here: [Blazor Server and SignalR and Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72820217/blazor-server-and-signalr-and-azure-ad) ... It turns out that I just had to add:

```
[AllowAnonymous()] //TODO: authorize...
    public class SignalrHub : Hub
    {
```

Hope it helps someone :)